# Parse String dd-MMM-yyyy to Date Object JavaScript without Libraries

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

For Example:

```
var dateStr = "21-May-2014";
```

I want the above to be into a valid Date Object.

Like, `var strConvt = new Date(dateStr);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need a simple parsing function like:

```
function parseDate(s) {
  var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};
  var p = s.split('-');
  return new Date(p[2], months[p[1].toLowerCase()], p[0]);
}

console.log(parseDate('21-May-2014'));  //  Wed 21 May 00:00:00 ... 2014
```

Comment: RobG, thanks for your Response. I received a reply. Exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Really handy and concise. Behaved the same on IE, FF, and Chrome (which is *not* the case for Date.parse()).  Interesting note: if you put in a slightly invalid date, such as '30-FEB-2019', it just counted into the next month, i.e., March 2, instead of throwing an exception. Could be a bonus or could be a harmful "corruption" depending on your situation, so FYI.