# parse string date to date object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a date in this format: '04-Aug-15'.

I want to be able to get a Date object in JS, I'm trying this:

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse('04-Aug-15', "MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

But I'm getting invalid date error message.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: you're telling the format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, then passing in a date that's `dd-mmm-yy`? what else would you expect if you hand someone a watermelon and tell them "this is an apple"?

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Mark, but do you know a way I can give a watermelon and get apple in my case...

Comment: `parse('04-aug-15', 'dd-mm-yy')`, or just HOPE that the parser is smart enough to handle `parse('04-aug-15')` as is without the format hint.

Comment: the `mm/dd/yyyy` stuff isn't for what you want the date to look like AFTER wards, it's to tell the system what the date you're passing in looks like RIGHT NOW.

Comment: This post helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058822/parse-string-dd-mmm-yyyy-to-date-object-javascript-without-libraries

Answer (score -1):

Just pass `new Date` the date string, and it'll turn it into a date.

```js
var stringDate='04-Aug-15';
var date=new Date(stringDate);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error message with your approach.

Comment: The spec doesn't mandate that the Date constructor should parse dd-mmm-yy format. This works on some browsers and on some browsers it does not.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to parse your date.

> var date = new Date(Date.parse("04-Dec-15"));

You can then print your date by the following function.

> window.alert( (date.getMonth() + 1) +
>   '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());