# How to get array data by filtering date dynamically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to display data based on dropdown selected value. The options of dropdown are last 10 new joinees, all joinees,last three month joinees and date selected base joinee details.
    I want to write function which filters data based on join date and display this details based on selected dropdown. I am totally get strucked in this one as i am new
    to angularjs. Any help would appreciate. 
    pls guide me on this issue.

```js
ctrl.getempjoin = function() {
  var reqObj = {
    empid: ctrl.empDetails.empid
  };
  employeeservice.getempjoinDetails(reqObj).then(function() {


      ctrl.empdetail = employeeservice.viewemployeeDetails;
      ctrl.empdetails = ctrl.empdetail.Responsefile;
      for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.empdetails.length; i++) {
        ctrl.empdetails[i].sal = ctrl.empdetails[i].sal.toString();

      }

    }
    PaginationService.initialize(ctrl.empdetails, 10);
  })




 //service file:

  var dropDownemp = [{
    optionId: '1',
    optionName: 'Last 10 new joinees join data'
  }, {
    optionId: '2',
    optionName: 'All employees join date'
  }, {
    optionId: '3',
    optionName: 'Select Date Range'
  }];

this.selectedFrequency = {
  value: ''
};

this.dropdownControl = componentFactory.create({
  type: 'dropdown',
  customValidation: function() {},
  dropdownOptions: dropDownemp,
  empty: {
    value: 'Select One Value'
  },

  value: {
    optionId: '1',
    optionName: 'Last 10 joinee detilas'
  },
  desktop: false,
  onSelect: function() {
    var selectVal = this.getValue().optionId;
    var selectName = this.getValue().optionName;
    that.dateControlFrom.value = '';
    that.dateControlTo.value = '';
    displayDetails(selectVal, selectName);
  }
});



function displayDetails(selectVal, selectName) {

  if (selectVal == "1") {
    that.requestObject = {
      empid: emploeeDetails.empid,
      fromDate: that.finalCurrentMonth,
      toDate: that.dateStartFormat
    }
    that.getEmployeeDetails(that.requestObject, ConfigService.ServiceUrl.getNewEmployeeDetails).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
  } else if (selectVal == "2") {
    that.requestObject = {
      empid: emploeeDetails.empid,
      fromDate: that.finalFirstDate,
      toDate: that.finalLastDate
    }
    that.getEmployeeDetails(that.requestObject, ConfigService.ServiceUrl.getFlexiSummaryDetails).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
  } else if (selectVal == "3") {
    openDateRange();
  }
```

```html
<div ngcontroller="mycontroller as myctrl" ng-repeat="employee in myctrl.empdetails.employees">
  <div>
    name
  </div>

  <div>
    {{employee.name}}
  </div>

  <div>
    city
  </div>

  <div>
    {{employee.city}}
  </div>

  <div>
    joindate
  </div>

  <div>
    {{employee.joindate}}
  </div>


  <div>
    salary
  </div>

  <div>
    {{employee.salary}}
  </div>
```

json file:

```
Employees:
{
[
joindate : "23-nov-2016",
name : "abc",
city:"a",
salary:10000
],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you are going to want to use a filter and `ng-repeat` to do the actual filtering in the view. You essentially have two problems:

1. Convert the `joindate` attribute from your input JSON into something that you can compare to other dates. I would parse it into a Javascript Date object. Since your date format appears to be `dd-MMM-yyyy`, there is a snippet on this other StackOverflow question ([Parse String dd-MMM-yyyy to Date Object JavaScript without Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058822/parse-string-dd-mmm-yyyy-to-date-object-javascript-without-libraries)) that can help you.
2. Build a custom AngularJS filter that does what you want based on the currently selected filtering option in the dropdown. This could look something like the filter defined below:

```
app.filter('myDateFilter', function() {
  // Helper from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058822/parse-string-dd-mmm-yyyy-to-date-object-javascript-without-libraries
  var parseDate = function(s) {
    var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                  jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};
    var p = s.split('-');
    return new Date(p[2], months[p[1].toLowerCase()], p[0]);
  }

  // Actual filter function
  // input is the original array of joinees
  // dateFilterType is the currently selected date filter from the dropdown
  // sd is the start date selected in the datepicker
  // ed is the end date selected in the datepicker
  return function(input, dateFilterType, sd, ed) {
    switch (dateFilterType) {
      case 1:
        // Create a date that is exactly 10 days ago
        var tendaysago = new Date();
        tendaysago.setDate(tendaysago.getDate() - 10);
        // Filter if joindate > tendaysago
        return input.filter(function(item) {
          return parseDate(item.joindate) > tendaysago;
        });
        return input;
        break;
      case 2:
        // Create a date that is exactly 3 months ago
        var threemonthsago = new Date();
        threemonthsago.setMonth(threemonthsago.getMonth() - 3);
        // Filter if joindate > threemonthsago
        return input.filter(function(item) {
          return parseDate(item.joindate) > threemonthsago;
        });
        break;
      case 3:
        // Using uib-datepicker, sd and ed inputs are already JS Date objects so we can just directly compare the item's parsed date with these inputs
        return input.filter(function(item) {
          var d = parseDate(item.joindate);
          return d > sd && d < ed;
        });
        break;
      default:
        return input;
    }
  }
});
```

You can then use this filter in your template like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="joinee in joinees | myDateFilter:selectedDateFilter:sdt:edt">
```

`myDateFilter` is the name of the defined filter, and parameters are passed in by separating them with a `:`.

Here is a simple plunkr that might help you: https://plnkr.co/edit/wfBUSaXOQ89DxdiMQkmm

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. In my case I have to display last ten people joining date....they may joined at any date

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want the last 10 people who joined? If so you can just sort the input based on the joindate, and then splice the array to only the last 10 joinees.

Comment: It is more over like last ten transaction, three month transaction details

Comment: Okay, I updated the fiddle to return the last 3 instead of those within 10 days. You can change it to the last 10 as needed, just change the parameter in the `slice` call, but I didn't want to add loads more records.