# APEX countdown timer between dates

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm trying to display the countdown timer between an enddate/time column and the system date/time column using below code. It's not displaying the timer.

I have created a page item P3_TIMER and it has a column P3_STARTDATE.

```
var timer;

var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()); //End date is the sys date

timer = setInterval(function() {
  timeBetweenDates(endDate);
}, 1000);

function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
  var dateEntered = :P3_STARTDATE;
  var now = new Date();
  var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (difference <= 0) {

    // Timer done
    clearInterval(timer);
  
  } else {
    
    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    $("#days").text(days);
    $("#hours").text(hours);
    $("#minutes").text(minutes);
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  }
$s('P3_TIMER',timer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to mix pl/sql and javascript. They're different languages and run in different environments.

```
function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
  var dateEntered = :P3_STARTDATE; >>> This is pl/sql 
  var now = new Date();
```

The P3_STARTDATE needs to be converted to a javascript date object. That cannot be directly, some parsing is needed as shown in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058822/parse-string-dd-mmm-yyyy-to-date-object-javascript-without-libraries).

For the example below the assumption is made that the date is passed in format DD-MON-YYYY.

```
var timer;

var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()); //End date is the sys date

timer = setInterval(function() {
  timeBetweenDates(endDate);
}, 1000);

function parseDate(s) {
  var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};
  var p = s.split('-');
  return new Date(p[2], months[p[1].toLowerCase()], p[0]);
}

function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
  var dateEntered = parseDate(apex.item( "P63_DATE" ).getValue() );
  var now = new Date();
  var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (difference <= 0) {

    // Timer done
    clearInterval(timer);
  
  } else {
    
    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    $("#days").text(days);
    $("#hours").text(hours);
    $("#minutes").text(minutes);
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  }
apex.item("P63_TIMER").setValue(`Days: ${days}, Hours: ${hours}, Minutes: ${minutes}, Seconds: ${seconds}`);
}
```